# How to access child and parent data from Core Data in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a viewcontroller (VC2) that allows you to enter a product name and description. This VC segues into another VC (VC3) that allows you to add several images. After going back to the VC2 there is a save button that dismisses VC2 and a viewcontroller with a tableview (VC1) that shows a list of product name and a thumbnail of the first image appears.

I'm saving product title and product description to a CoreData Entity called ProductDetails. I'm saving the images to a core Data Entity called ProductImages. I've made a one to many relationship between the ProductDetails and ProductImages.

I am able to load a list of the product titles in VC1 using NSFetchRequest. But I haven't been able to figure out how to load the child images in the same VC- and specifically the first image. I think I need to be using NSPredicate but I haven't been able to find a solution online. Any help would be greatly appreciated.[Core Data Entities and relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSVHw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship `image` in your `ProductDetails` entity is also a property that you can access like any other property.

```
let images = productDetail.image
```

`images` will be a set of `ProductImage`, `Set<ProductImage>`

Comment: Thanks. So it's good to know I can access the images as attributes. But I am getting nil in my productDetails.image when I have added images. I must have skipped a step somewhere.